# Doesn't Fired Javascript Functions outside .cshtml in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am newbie in ASP.NET MVC, I hope somebody can help me to solve my issue.
i had created a simple registration form inside that i had included a *.js file source. *.js file contains some functions, the problem is the functions never fired .

**.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/style/sample.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/samplesrcipt.js"></script>
</head>
```

// Textbox control

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.FirstName, new { @class = "class1", title = "Enter FirstName", id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Enter name", onkeydown = "return TextField(event)" })
```

I want to call a function when onkeydown event occures.The function definition is written in a `samplesrcipt.js` file.

**samplescript.js**

```
function TextField(e) {
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 56)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 9) {
        return true;
    }
    return false

};
```

When i write the javascript code inside .cshtml it will works but when i write it inside a *.js file then it will not fired , please help me to solve this issue.Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: is the relative path '../../Scripts/samplesrcipt.js' OK?

Comment: @IvanSivak yes the path is ok , i had fix a breakpoint inside .js file and it will fired when page loads, the problem is corresponding function will not fired.

Comment: You should remove the semicolon (;) at the end of your TextField function

Comment: @frosdqy no use, removed the semicolon but will not fired

Comment: are you sure js file path is correct?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes sure the path is correct

Comment: instead of ``onkeydown = "return TextField(event)"`` do like this: ``onkeydown = "return TextField(this)"``

Comment: Maybe some problem with the js file name? In the js path you use **samplesrcipt.js**, I think should be **samplescript.js**

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i had tried but again the same situation, i think sample.js i not detecting  but i don't know where i loose

Comment: @frosdqy it is fired when i change the name samplesrcipt.js to samplescript.js. Actually it was a spelling mistake but i had drag the .js reference to my .cshtml, so in my .cshtml and the original .js file has same name , it was samplesrcipt.js . but when i change the name it fired.

Comment: try including the script at the end of the page instead of head

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe ya sure i will do , but can you explain why it needed ?

Comment: Just to be sure the control with which you are trying to call this funciton is registered before the code is rendered. Must make no difference though but still..

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe i had solved this problem, the problems is because of i didn't clear the Cache . when i clear the Cache of browser it works fine

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe ok that's fine , anyway the problem is not related to that , it is related to cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i had found the solution,

the code is perfectly alright, the problem reside in `cache memory.` Each time when i call the java script it will take it from `browser cache`, when i clear the `cache` it work perfectly.

Comment: You missed this conversation I hope. "@ArunprasanthKV Do you see any error in browser console. Remove the style reference for now. and do one thing, in document.ready function put an alert and see if it alerts in page load. Also try clearing the browser cache –  user2773448 "

Answer (score 1):

Please check the browser console and see if you get any error. do one thing remove the reference you added and just drag the file into your page and see.

I think **link href="@Url.Content("~/style/sample.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />** is causing the problem. The quots are not well formatted.

Comment: Thanks for you replay , the script already i had dragged from source so sure the path is correct , the second thing about .css reference it was a mistake now i correct that but it still shows the same problem

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Do you see any error in browser console. Remove the style reference for now.  and do one thing, in document.ready function put an alert and see if it alerts in page load. Also try clearing the browser cache

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Still if issue is not fixed. Try keeping the reference outside the head tag.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Check your script file name is it "samplescript" or "samplesrcipt" ?

Comment: the name has some spelling mistake, but the name in original file is also the same , so why we worried about that?? but when i change the name it fired i don't know why it happened like that

Comment: Thanks for the replay and +1 for correcting me .css reference

Comment: Did u try this  <script src="~/Scripts/samplesrcipt.js"></script>